# Sorting on associated domain objects with DetachedCriteria

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Having such a domain model:

```
package com
class Bar {
    String barName
}  

package com
class Foo {

    static belongsTo = [bar: Bar]

    String fooName
    Integer fooAge

}
```

I'm able to construct following criteria, some context:([grails list.gsp / g:sortableColumn: being able to sort on associated domain objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7862077/grails-list-gsp-gsortablecolumn-being-able-to-sort-on-associated-domain-obje)):

```
   params.sort = 'bar.barName'
   def foos = Foo.createCriteria().list(params){
        gt 'fooAge', 10
   }
```

but when using DetachedCriteria it fails:

```
    params.sort = 'bar.barName'
    def foos =  new DetachedCriteria(Foo).build {
        gt 'fooAge', 10
    }.list(params)
```

exception:

```
could not resolve property: bar.barName of: com.Foo. Stacktrace follows:
Message: could not resolve property: bar.barName of: com.Foo
    Line | Method
->>   87 | initialize    in grails.gorm.PagedResultList
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|     50 | getTotalCount in     ''
|     26 | $tt__index .  in com.FooController$$EPB9xU8u
|    198 | doFilter      in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter . .  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|   1145 | runWorker     in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run           in java.lang.Thread
```

Is there a way around this?

Comment: I can't give you a definitive answer, but maybe this can give you a hint for possible solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104641/grails-sort-by-nested-attributes

Comment: seems like createAlias is not entirely supported with DetachedCriteria: https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-8741

Comment: If it helps, I use some old (googled) code that works and looks like this:

def dc = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Example.class, 'e')
...
dc.createAlias('e.hasManyExampleProperty', 'hasManyExampleProperty', CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN)